# Using c library variable/struct member in C++ class member function

Tags: c++, c, alsa

I am recently started reading about alsa api. I was trying to write a C++ class which opens default device and reads basic parameters like maximum rate, number of channels etc.

My class header file is:

```
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
#include <iostream>
class AlsaParam{
    snd_pcm_t* pcm_handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t* hw_param;
    ....

    public:
      int pcm_open();
       .....

};
```

Inside pcm_open()

```
int AlsaParam::pcm_open(){
     int err = snd_pcm_open(&pcm_handle, "default", SND_PCM_STREAM_PLAYBACK, 0);
     if(err > -1)
         std::cout << pcm_handle->name << std::endl;   //Just to test if it works

return err;
}
```

I get following error:

```
error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘snd_pcm_t {aka struct _snd_pcm}’
std::cout << pcm_handle->name << std::endl;
                       ^
 In file included from /usr/include/alsa/asoundlib.h:54:0,
             from alsa_param.h:4,
             from alsa_param.cpp:1:
 /usr/include/alsa/pcm.h:341:16: error: forward declaration of ‘snd_pcm_t {aka struct _snd_pcm}’
  typedef struct _snd_pcm snd_pcm_t;
            ^
```

From this error I understood that asoundlib.h only uses typedef for struct snd_pcm_t but it is defined somewhere else. Am I correct? Is there any way to solve this problem? In general if we are including some c library functions in C++ class which are the things to remember/ avoid? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

The layout of `struct _snd_pcm` is deliberately hidden from programs because it might change in a new library version.

To get a PCM device's name, call [snd_pcm_name](http://www.alsa-project.org/alsa-doc/alsa-lib/group___p_c_m.html#ga5031edc0422df8db1f70af056a12dd77):

```
cout << snd_pcm_name(pcm_handle) << endl;
```

(Pretty much everything in ALSA needs such a function call.)

Comment: snd_pcm_name(pcm_handle) works. As you said layout of struct _snd_pcm may change, it is not exposed in library api and its implementation is hidden?

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing wrong with your code. Just that there is missing declaration of `struct _snd_pcm`, the header you included only has the typedef: `typedef struct _snd_pcm snd_pcm_t;`

What you can do is look up (maybe on the internet or in the manual) for the header that has`struct _snd_pcm` declaration and include it in your code.

Answer (score -1):

There are a few differences in declaration syntax between C and C++.

Since you're compiling a C++ file but including a C header inside it, you probably need to make the compiler interpret it the right way.

Try this:

```
extern "C"
{
#include <alsa/asoundlib.h>
}

#include <iostream>
class AlsaParam{
    snd_pcm_t* pcm_handle;
    snd_pcm_hw_params_t* hw_param;
    ...
```